# Cannot cancel pg_routing query in local database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have tried to cancel the hung query after a pg_routing query, but cannot.  I have encountered this problem previously with pg_routing, but ended up really messing up the local database and had to delete and redo, which I don't want to do every time this happens when testing a query locally.

The following is the pgr_dijkstra function I am running:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_shortest_routes_sk()
    RETURNS TABLE (
        source_vertex bigint,
        destination_vertex bigint,
        source_id int,
        destination_id int,
        cost float,
        sequence int[],
        edges bigint[],
        nodes bigint[],
        geom geometry(LineString, 26913) 
    )
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _source int;
    _destinations int[];
    _start timestamptz := clock_timestamp();
    _stop timestamptz;

BEGIN  

    RAISE NOTICE '% - start time', substr(cast(clock_timestamp() AS varchar), 12, 8);

     _destinations := ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT tv FROM public.rd_vertices_lookup);
    RAISE NOTICE 'destination vertices: %', _destinations;

    FOR _source IN
        SELECT DISTINCT(fv) FROM public.rd_vertices_lookup
    LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE 'start vertex: %', _source;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT  
            _source::bigint AS source_vertex,
            MIN(r.end_vid)::bigint AS destination_vertex,
            vl.fid::int AS source_id,
            vl.tid::int AS destination_id,
            SUM(r.cost) AS cost,
            array_agg(r.path_seq) AS sequence,
            array_agg(r.edge) AS edges,
            array_agg(r.node) AS nodes,
            ST_Collect(ws.geom) AS geom
        FROM pgr_dijkstra(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM public.rd_strms',
            _source, 
            _destinations, 
            directed := true
        ) AS r
        JOIN public.rd_strms AS ws
        ON r.edge = ws.id
        JOIN public.rd_vertices_lookup AS vl
        ON _source = vl.fv
        AND r.end_vid = vl.tv 
        GROUP BY end_vid, vl.fid, vl.tid
        ORDER BY cost
        LIMIT 1;
        
    END LOOP;

    _stop = clock_timestamp();
    RAISE NOTICE '% - completed in % seconds', substr(cast(clock_timestamp() AS varchar), 12, 8), to_seconds((_stop - _start)::text);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.sk_shortest_routes_rd;
CREATE TABLE public.sk_shortest_routes_rd 
AS SELECT 
    rd_result.source_vertex,
    rd_result.destination_vertex,
    rd_result.source_id,
    rd_result.destination_id,
    rd_result.cost,
    rd_result.sequence,
    rd_result.edges,
    rd_result.nodes,
    ST_CollectionExtract(rd_result.geom) AS geom
FROM find_shortest_routes_sk() AS rd_result;

ALTER TABLE public.sk_shortest_routes_rd ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have tried the following to retrieve active queries and nothing comes up:

```
SELECT pid, query_start, query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

I believe there is an active query that wasn't terminating because I received the message after running my query a 2nd time:

```
ERROR:  cannot DROP TABLE "sk_shortest_routes_rd" because it is being used by active queries in this session

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.sk_shortest_routes_rd" PL/pgSQL function find_shortest_routes_sk() line 51 at SQL statement SQL statement "CREATE TABLE public.sk_shortest_routes_rd   AS SELECT   rd_result.source_vertex,    
            rd_result.destination_vertex,   
            rd_result.source_id,    
            rd_result.destination_id,   
            rd_result.cost,     
            rd_result.sequence,     
            rd_result.edges,    
            rd_result.nodes,    
            ST_CollectionExtract(rd_result.geom) AS geom  FROM find_shortest_routes_sk() AS rd_result"  PL/pgSQL function find_shortest_routes_sk() line 52 at SQL statement  SQL state: 55006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not that I had a query running, but that my function, as expected, was recursively creating the table public.sk_shortest_routes_rd becasue it was inside the function call.